# Frayed and Taped Wire from HVAC

Tags: hvac

Buying a house and there is a wire that comes from the external HVAC unit and goes to the house. It looks like the wire has been frayed or cut and it taped with what looks like masking tape. I'm adept at structural stuff but I don't do HVAC or electric. Can anyone tell me what this is and if it is a major fix? Pictures attached.[image]

Answer (score 3):

That looks like the control wire. It's low voltage and safe as is but might have problems due to water intrusion. You should replace it or have it replaced. If the colors are matched at both ends, replacing it can be quite straightforward.